# Swing and JavaFX: how to combine?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I'm using Webcam Capture and writig application with JavaFX GUI. WebcamPanel extends JPanel so it's easy to use in Swing. Now I need to display video captured from webcam in my app during capturing. So I need to place JPanel into AnchorPane. After examining Oracle documentationi found out that there are no explanations for encapsulating Swing components into JavaFX scene. So the question is: is it possible to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm : you can place Java FX nodes in a JPanel but to do the opposite, you would need [Java FX 8](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).

Comment: @assylias didn't know about java fx8 xD ,but swing it's gonna to be deprecated in java8

Comment: @nachokk Swing is not going to be deprecated in Java 8.

Comment: Why closed? It would be great to describe all the options you have to mix Swing and JavaFX nodes. @Eugene you should edit your question to specifically ask something like that. And there are options to include Swing nodes inside a JavaFX application (with limitations and risks).